# PHP retireval error from table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete a users records from a database, I want to delete all affiliated information from the user from the tables and I have the following php code used to delete records from my mysql database.

```
function delete_records($array_refer)
    {
        global $link;
        foreach ($array_refer as $key => $array_value) {
        $table_name = substr($key, 0, -3);
            foreach ($array_value as $value) {
                $delete = "DELETE from $table_name where $key = $value";
                $exec_delete = @mysqli_query($link, $delete);
                if (!$exec_delete) {
                    rollback_die("Records from $table_name could not be deleted because of: ".mysqli_error($link));
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @mysqli_query($link, "SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");
    $select_sui = "SELECT 
    shirt_users.*, 
    shirt_users_types.*, 
    shirt_orders.*, 
    shirt_shipping_addresses.*, 
    shirt_billing_addresses.*, 
    shirt_credit_cards.* 
    FROM shirt_users 
    LEFT JOIN shirt_users_types ON shirt_users.shirt_users_id = shirt_users_types.shirt_users_id
    LEFT JOIN shirt_orders ON shirt_users_types.shirt_orders_id = shirt_orders.shirt_orders_id
    LEFT JOIN shirt_shipping_addresses ON shirt_orders.shirt_shipping_addresses_id = shirt_shipping_addresses.shirt_shipping_addresses_id
    LEFT JOIN shirt_billing_addresses ON shirt_orders.shirt_billing_addresses_id = shirt_billing_addresses.shirt_billing_addresses_id
    LEFT JOIN shirt_credit_cards ON shirt_orders.shirt_credit_cards_id = shirt_credit_cards.shirt_credit_cards_id
    WHERE
    shirt_users.shirt_users_id = $shirt_users_id";

    $exec_select_sui = @mysqli_query($link, $select_sui);
```

When I run this, I get the following error message:

```
The shirt_users_id is:4
Records from shirt_users_types could not be deleted because of: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Any idea what this means? I understand there is a problem when it comes to retrieving the data from shirt_users_types, but I do not see any syntax error that it is warning me about?

Comment: You need to inspect the queries that are being executed.  There's some syntax problem in the query, but it can't be identified without seeing the query as executed.  `echo $delete;` in your loop to debug...

Comment: It doesn't look like $link is defined at all. You declare it in your function as a global var but never define what it is.

Comment: The error is in your SQL statement. I'll suggest that you do an `echo $select_sui` and copy the SQL statement and paste that into PHPMyAdmin's query window, and debug from there

Comment: Given that there's no character specified in `near '' at line 1`, it seems likely there's an empty `$value`.

Comment: Does the `$key` exist and isn't it a restricted word?

Comment: Can you give `var_dump($array_refer)` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `$key` and `$value` exist and aren't they reserved words? Also you should try `'$value'`.

Comment: Thank you very much.. Such a careless mistake on my part! This fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using,

`$delete = "DELETE from $table_name where $key = '".$value."' ";`

instead of

`$delete = "DELETE from $table_name where $key = $value";`

Comment: Tried this, doesnt do anything. Thanks for the suggestion though.